# How to get channel name using YouTube API?

Tags: ios, swift, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I would like to get channels name of a videos but it is giving the playlists name. I am currently using this URL `var urlString = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&pageToken=\(pageToken)&playlistId=PLFgquLnL59alCl_2TQvOiD5Vgm1hCaGSI&key=\(apiKey)"`

It is giving me something like this right now.

```
["items": <__NSArrayI 0x1c0472540>(
{
    etag = "\"DuHzAJ-eQIiCIp7p4ldoVcVAOeY/Vq7FiiHfUpgAr9yq9YxmBXwSLrE\"";
    id = UExGZ3F1TG5MNTlhbENsXzJUUXZPaUQ1VmdtMWhDYUdTSS4xNDU2QkYwRjk0NkZBOEVD;
    kind = "youtube#playlistItem";
    snippet =     {
        channelId = "UC-9-kyTW8ZkZNDHQJ6FgpwQ";
        channelTitle = Music;
        description = "\U201cThis is America\U201d by Childish Gambino http://smarturl.it/TcIgA\nDirector: Hiro Murai\nProducer: Jason Cole of Doomsday with Ibra Ake and Fam Rothstein of Wolf + Rothstein\ntour tickets and merchandise available at childishgambino.com";
        playlistId = "PLFgquLnL59alCl_2TQvOiD5Vgm1hCaGSI";
        position = 0;
        publishedAt = "2018-05-18T11:29:31.000Z";
        resourceId =         {
            kind = "youtube#video";
            videoId = VYOjWnS4cMY;
        };
        thumbnails =         {
            default =             {
                height = 90;
                url = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/VYOjWnS4cMY/default.jpg";
                width = 120;
            };
            high =             {
                height = 360;
                url = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/VYOjWnS4cMY/hqdefault.jpg";
                width = 480;
            };
            maxres =             {
                height = 720;
                url = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/VYOjWnS4cMY/maxresdefault.jpg";
                width = 1280;
            };
            medium =             {
                height = 180;
                url = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/VYOjWnS4cMY/mqdefault.jpg";
                width = 320;
            };
            standard =             {
                height = 480;
                url = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/VYOjWnS4cMY/sddefault.jpg";
                width = 640;
            };
        };
        title = "Childish Gambino - This Is America (Official Video)";
    };
},
```

As you can see that the channelTitle is "Music". How can i get that real channelTitle ?

Answer (score 4):

Take the channelID from any playlist or video and make a [Channels:list API call](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#usage) with the channelID and `part='snippet'`. The results will have the channel title and other details.

Example URL: `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?id=UC_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw&part=snippet&key=API_KEY`

Response:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
 "etag": "\"DuHzAJ-eQIiCIp7p4ldoVcVAOeY/3xuQp_Bnwrc1tW3bBIDi6LxzB7I\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#channel",
   "etag": "\"DuHzAJ-eQIiCIp7p4ldoVcVAOeY/czbu6JihYqowBUI2jn5-PBL7TvY\"",
   "id": "UC_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw",
   "snippet": {
    "title": "Google Developers",
    "description": "The Google Developers channel features talks from events, educational series, best practices, tips, and the latest updates across our products and platforms.",
    "customUrl": "GoogleDevelopers",
    "publishedAt": "2007-08-23T00:34:43.000Z",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/a-/AJLlDp2JcYTd7j-M2CUsBC2zO-p6TVYo0bE8dsS_fw=s88-mo-c-c0xffffffff-rj-k-no",
      "width": 88,
      "height": 88
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/a-/AJLlDp2JcYTd7j-M2CUsBC2zO-p6TVYo0bE8dsS_fw=s240-mo-c-c0xffffffff-rj-k-no",
      "width": 240,
      "height": 240
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/a-/AJLlDp2JcYTd7j-M2CUsBC2zO-p6TVYo0bE8dsS_fw=s800-mo-c-c0xffffffff-rj-k-no",
      "width": 800,
      "height": 800
     }
    },
    "localized": {
     "title": "Google Developers",
     "description": "The Google Developers channel features talks from events, educational series, best practices, tips, and the latest updates across our products and platforms."
    }
   }
  }
 ]
}
```